How do i style an HTML standard input-type-color element?
I am having trouble styling the default <input type="color"> element using CSS.
For reference, say i have the following elements and CSS styling:


#myColorPicker {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
<label for="myColorPicker">Select a color:</label>
<input type="color" name="myColorPicker" id="myColorPicker">



This changes the "outside"-rectangle's border-radius property only. Is there a way to also change the "inside"-rectangle's border-radius property? With "inside"-rectangle I mean the colored rectangle actually showing the color picked by the user.
It seems to be trickier than expected.
Thank you in advance!

Are you aware that different browsers/OS show color pickers in different ways? Try e.g. Chrome on Windows versus Safari on an iPhone. If you want consistency you'll probably have to implement your own.

Does the duplicate question help? It seems to have nothing to do with the user color choice rectangle.

Styling an input element of type "color" have limited styling options for the native color input due to its complex structure.
You'll often need to create a custom color picker using JavaScript or an external library.
To achieve styling on the "inside rectangle" i.e. the rectangle filled with the color you'll have to use the browser webkit selector ::-webkit-color-swatch
and here is your new code


#myColorPicker::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
<label for="myColorPicker">Select a color:</label>
<input type="color" name="myColorPicker" id="myColorPicker">




This answer could be improved by noting that that solution likely won't work for all user agents

Thank you guys!
I realize now why it won't work for all user agents, and I realize I should probably implement my own. But I thought I ought to understand the behaviour for the standard element before going off on a tangent doing things I do not 100% understand. Thanks for the replys.
